# Document input track change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need help on this one:

In the document there are several input fields with `<div class="quantity"><input .. >`
This is automatically generated by the system and  I have no access to alter this.

So I need a way with jQuery to track the `onchange` function when the input changes.

What is a good way to achieve this?

```
var updateInput = document.getElementById(".quantity input");
            
    if ( updateInput ????? ) { 
          alert("Hallo") 
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getElementById does not work on class names. You asked for jquery, why not use [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)?

```
$('.quantity input').change(function() {
    alert('Input changed');
});
```

From the manual:

> The change event is sent to an element
>   when its value changes. This event is
>   limited to `<input>` elements,
>   `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>`
>   elements. For select boxes,
>   checkboxes, and radio buttons, the
>   event is fired immediately when the
>   user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the
>   event is deferred until the element
>   loses focus.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/yzGYU/

Comment: the change function works, but only once ... if you keep change the input field - the alert doenst fire up anymore. any suggestion?

Comment: Should be working fine, updated answer with notes from docs and a demo. If you want the check the value of text input with every keystroke you will need to use [keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

Comment: hmm wierd on the demo it just works perfectly.. but when i apply the script, even using keyup or keydown, or altering the target classes.. results remain the same.. it update once after out focus, and then doesnt work anymore. I updated the info with the code that I cannot alter. there still be something i am doing wrong.

Comment: @CCCam: If you can put a test case up with your actual code on jsfiddle I or someone else can probably solve it for you.

Comment: I got the problem almost solved, instead using change, using the live function instead. go test more with this .live function <3 thanks for leading me the right direction Madmartigan!